# How much should we augment our training data?

Tags: machine-learning, data-preprocessing, data-augmentation, mask-rcnn

I am wondering how much I should extend my training set with data augmentation. Is there somewhere a pre-defined number I can go with?

Suppose I have 10000 images, can I go as far as 10x or 20x times, to get 100000 and 200000, respectively, images? I am wondering how will this impact model training. I am using a mask R-CNN.

Comment: If hardware and training time isn't a limitation, just try it and see when validation accuracy starts to decrease.

Comment: Maybe you should describe which model you are trying to use (I suppose it's a neural network) and how you are augmenting your training data. There are several ways you can augment the training data.

Comment: @nbro Mask RCNN, this is the model.

Comment: Literally augment as much as possible as long as a valid image is still produced. The gold standard for CV is human equivalent understanding. Now you dont need to preagument them, they can be augmented at sampling time.